# How to calculate running total (month to date) in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregation, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to calculate a month-to-date total using SQL Server 2008.

I'm trying to generate a month-to-date count at the level of activities and representatives. Here are the results I want to generate:

```
| REPRESENTATIVE_ID | MONTH | WEEK | TOTAL_WEEK_ACTIVITY_COUNT | MONTH_TO_DATE_ACTIVITIES_COUNT |
|-------------------|-------|------|---------------------------|--------------------------------|
|                40 |     7 | 7/08 |                         1 |                              1 |
|                40 |     8 | 8/09 |                         1 |                              1 |
|                40 |     8 | 8/10 |                         1 |                              2 |
|                41 |     7 | 7/08 |                         2 |                              2 |
|                41 |     8 | 8/08 |                         4 |                              4 |
|                41 |     8 | 8/09 |                         3 |                              7 |
|                41 |     8 | 8/10 |                         1 |                              8 |
```

From the following tables:

**ACTIVITIES_FACT table**

```
+-------------------+------+-----------+  
| Representative_ID | Date | Activity  |  
+-------------------+------+-----------+  
|                41 | 8/03 | Call      |  
|                41 | 8/04 | Call      |  
|                41 | 8/05 | Call      |  
+-------------------+------+-----------+
```

**LU_TIME table**

```
+-------+-----------------+--------+  
| Month | Date            | Week   |  
+-------+-----------------+--------+  
|     8 | 8/01            | 8/08   |  
|     8 | 8/02            | 8/08   |  
|     8 | 8/03            | 8/08   |  
|     8 | 8/04            | 8/08   |  
|     8 | 8/05            | 8/08   |  
+-------+-----------------+--------+
```

I'm not sure how to do this: I keep running into problems with multiple-counting or aggregations not being allowed in subqueries.

Comment: How **ACTIVITIES_FACT** and **LU_TIME** tables are related?

Comment: @Mariej Los : The tables aren't related except insofar as every date in ACTIVITIES_FACT also is in LU_TIME. I'm using LU_TIME to aggregate data at the week level and month levels: LU_TIME provides a mapping between days, weeks and months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A [running total](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total) is the summation of a sequence of numbers which is
>   updated each time a new number is added to the sequence, simply by
>   adding the value of the new number to the running total.

I **THINK** He wants a running total for Month by each Representative_Id, so a simple `group by` week isn't enough. He probably wants his `Month_To_Date_Activities_Count` to be updated at the end of every week.

This query gives a **running total (month to end-of-week date)** ordered by Representative_Id, Week

```
SELECT a.Representative_ID, l.month, l.Week, Count(*) AS Total_Week_Activity_Count
    ,(SELECT  count(*)
        FROM ACTIVITIES_FACT a2
        INNER JOIN LU_TIME l2 ON a2.Date = l2.Date
        AND a.Representative_ID = a2.Representative_ID
        WHERE l2.week <=  l.week
        AND l2.month = l.month) Month_To_Date_Activities_Count
FROM ACTIVITIES_FACT a
INNER JOIN LU_TIME l ON a.Date = l.Date
GROUP BY a.Representative_ID, l.Week, l.month
ORDER BY a.Representative_ID, l.Week
```

---

```
| REPRESENTATIVE_ID | MONTH | WEEK | TOTAL_WEEK_ACTIVITY_COUNT | MONTH_TO_DATE_ACTIVITIES_COUNT |
|-------------------|-------|------|---------------------------|--------------------------------|
|                40 |     7 | 7/08 |                         1 |                              1 |
|                40 |     8 | 8/09 |                         1 |                              1 |
|                40 |     8 | 8/10 |                         1 |                              2 |
|                41 |     7 | 7/08 |                         2 |                              2 |
|                41 |     8 | 8/08 |                         4 |                              4 |
|                41 |     8 | 8/09 |                         3 |                              7 |
|                41 |     8 | 8/10 |                         1 |                              8 |
```

[SQL Fiddle Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b785/4/0)

Comment: Thanks, you're correct about what I meant to ask. Sorry the question was unclear.

Comment: Worked great! And I really appreciate your putting together the SQL Fiddle sample.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question:

```
SELECT af.Representative_ID
, lt.Week
, COUNT(af.Activity) AS Qnt
FROM ACTIVITIES_FACT af
INNER JOIN LU_TIME lt ON lt.Date = af.date
GROUP BY af.Representative_ID, lt.Week
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/181cfb/1)

Comment: This is the same way that I understand it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think the question is unclear, nonetheless he wrote "running total" in the title and this is not a running total..

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - Thanks for posting responses. You're right that the question was unclear. I edited the question to include a larger result set. I'll use SQLFiddle next time as well so responders don't have to re-create the sample data.

Answer (score 3):

```
Representative_ID   Week                           Month_To_Date_Activities_Count
 41                 2013-08-01 00:00:00.000        1
 41                 2013-08-08 00:00:00.000        3
```

```
 USE tempdb;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('#ACTIVITIES_FACT','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ACTIVITIES_FACT;
CREATE TABLE #ACTIVITIES_FACT
(
 Representative_ID INT NOT NULL
,Date DATETIME NULL
, Activity VARCHAR(500) NULL
)

IF OBJECT_ID('#LU_TIME','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #LU_TIME;
CREATE TABLE #LU_TIME
(
 Month INT
,Date DATETIME
,Week DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #ACTIVITIES_FACT(Representative_ID,Date,Activity)
VALUES
 (41,'7/31/2013','Chat')
,(41,'8/03/2013','Call')
,(41,'8/04/2013','Call')
,(41,'8/05/2013','Call')

INSERT INTO #LU_TIME(Month,Date,Week)
VALUES
 (8,'7/31/2013','8/01/2013')
,(8,'8/01/2013','8/08/2013')
,(8,'8/02/2013','8/08/2013')
,(8,'8/03/2013','8/08/2013')
,(8,'8/04/2013','8/08/2013')
,(8,'8/05/2013','8/08/2013')
--Begin Query
SELECT      AF.Representative_ID
            ,LU.Week
            ,COUNT(*) AS Month_To_Date_Activities_Count
FROM        #ACTIVITIES_FACT AS AF
INNER JOIN  #LU_TIME AS LU
    ON      AF.Date = LU.Date
Group By    AF.Representative_ID
            ,LU.Week
```

Comment: Your solution works well and answers the question. Thanks very much! I don't have the reputation to vote up, so I hope someone else can.